# Add URL into Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to add this :

type: "POST",
url: "login.php", in JS code below (exactly in comment "do your ajax call and processing here...":

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#submit_butt").click( function()
        {
            var conf =
            {
                frequency: 5000,
                spread: 5,
                duration: 600
            };
        /* do your AJAX call and processing here...
        ....
        ....
        */
        // this is the call we make when the AJAX callback function indicates a login failure 
            $("#login").vibrate(conf);
            // let's also display a notification
            if($("#errormsg").text() == "")
            {
            $("#loginform").append();       
            // clear the fields to discourage brute forcing :)
            $("#password").val("");
            document.forms['login_form'].elements['username'].focus();
            }
            else
            {

            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
/* do your AJAX call and processing here...
....
....
*/
```

With

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "login.php"
});
```

Comment: Hi, I using the vibrate effect form login. I tried code with your suggest but it still can't go to login.php.

Comment: What do you mean "can't go to login.php"? It doesn't send the ajax request at all?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code for Ajax Processing

```
$.ajax({
  url: "login.php",
  data: param, 
  success: function(result) {
        alert('SUCCESS');
  }
});
```

Comment: Your login.php should be wrapped in quotes.